# Ubuntu + kde-standard + dual monitor

Tags: 13.04, multiple-monitors, kubuntu, resolution, kde

After couple of years, I decided to return to Ubuntu, from Debian (sid). I used to work with KDE, so I installed Ubuntu 13.04 and "kde-standard" on my laptop.

**SHORT:**
"Display configuration" is not available in Ubuntu+kde-standard, so I can not configure two displays... and default configuration is wrong. Tested Ubuntu+Unity and Ubuntu+Gnome3... both works well. Installing Kubuntu insted Ubuntu works, but I prefer Ubuntu.

**LONG**:
I have two displays for my laptop: the laptop one and an external display that is connected throw HDMI port. Under Ubuntu+Unity, I can configure resolution and displays relative position (one relative to the other)... but not under KDE... and KDE does not use automatically the right configuration, it uses a mirrored screen, with 4:3 resolution on both screens.

In KDE, this should be fixed changing the configuration in "System Settings -> Display and Monitor".. where "Display Configuration" menu should be available, together with "Screen Locker". But there is no "Display Configuration" menu, only "Screen Locker", so I can not change resolution, what screen is the primary one, relative position, etc.

Tried Gnome 3 under Ubuntu and settings works perfectly.

Now, I have installed Kubuntu instead Ubuntu and there is "Display Configuration" menu... but I prefer >>>> Ubuntu... x_x

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**KDE desktop metapackages**

There are many ways to install the KDE desktop. The kde-standard (http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/kde-standard ) doesn't have the KDE screen setup modules as dependencies. They can be installed later.

**KDE screen setup modules**

The new: Kscreen

```
:~$ apt-cache show kscreen 
Package: kscreen 
Priority: extra 
Section: universe/kde

Description: KDE monitor hotplug and screen handling  The KDE multiple
monitor support is trying be as smart as possible  adapting the
behavior of it to each use case making the configuration  of monitors
as simple as plugging them to your computer.  

This package contains the modules and plugins for monitor hotplut and  automatic screen handling. 

Homepage:https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/base/kscreen
```

[image]

The old: kde-workspace-randr

```
:~$ apt-cache show kde-workspace-randr 
Package: kde-workspace-randr
Priority: optional 
Section: universe/kde

Description: randr tools from kde-workspace  Screen resize and rotate
tools from KDE Workspace. 

Homepage: http://www.kde.org/
```

[image]

Both modules can be installed side by side. Both have own quirks: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?62632-How-do-I-undo-display-resolution-changes

Comment: Isn't this a bug? With clean install I had kscreen installed however (on a different machine) after upgrade from 12.10 there's no graphical display configuration tool

Comment: kde-workspace-randr is not available on ubuntu 18.04 and up

Answer (score 0):

What is your video card ?

In my case, I have an nvidia video card, I can use the Nvidia X server Settings to enable the Twinview.

Now I can use my two screen independantly

Nikos

Comment: Hi, thank you for yout answer!
My graphic card is an nvidia 650M with optimus, integrated card is a Intel 4000HD (from Ivy processor). But I have not installed nvidia drivers or something like bumblebee (at least, manually...).. neither on Ubuntu+kde-standard/Unity/Gnome3 nor Kubuntu.
So Intel 4000HD is what is running.

I'll try to search for nvidia drivers (bumblebee?), thank you!