# Persistent dual-monitor configuration on KDE4

Tags: multiple-monitors, kde

I am using KDE on a laptop with Ubuntu 12.04.  In the office I am using an additional monitor for work. When I leave the office, I take my laptop with me.

My issue is that KDE cannot remember my dual-monitor setup the next day.

On Ubuntu Unity this is not an issue. It always remembers the configuration.

Has anybody here found a way to get around this issue? I need it to be persistent so that I don't have to do this each day.

Thanks. :)

EDIT:

Ubuntu - 12.04.3

KDE - 4.12.0

I am using the kubuntu-ppa/backports for Precise.

Note: KDE has System Settings > Display And Monitor > Size And Orientation to handle multiple monitor setup.

Comment: Could you tell your KDE version and what tool are you using ? The old kde-workspace-randr module has this bug: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183143 . Earlier: http://askubuntu.com/questions/292776/ubuntu-kde-standard-dual-monitor

Comment: I have edited the post to include the version. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KDE 4.11 has a new module called [`KScreen`](http://www.afiestas.org/kscreen-1-0-released/). It does what you need.

But you have on old Ubuntu version. Not sure that you can backport KScreen to your KDE version.

You should upgrade KDE to version 4.11+

Comment: Seems to work. Tested it just a few minutes ago. Did not do a reboot, but I removed 2nd monitor,  did a logout --> login, plugged it back in, and the 2nd monitor came to life without me doing anything.

Comment: Just a remark: One should set up the orientation and hit the "Defaults" button.