# How can I display laptop screen on the TV by HDMI in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, display, screen

I have installed Kubuntu 13.10 on my laptop. 
My problem is when I connect my TV to my laptop using a HDMI cable, the 2 screens act as seperate screens, so what is visible on my laptop screen isn't on the TV and also the other way around.
how can I make the TV duplicate what's on my laptop screen, so they both become duplicates of each other?

I was using Ubuntu and it was easy to change it from the appearance settings in Unity, but I couldn't find where I can change this in KDE in Kubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at Display Configuration you can do it.go through this page :

> [Ubuntu + kde-standard + dual monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292776/ubuntu-kde-standard-dual-monitor)